# How to sort the following array of objects and strings?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have the following:

```
myitems = [{'name': 'Jorden'},"Kelsey", "Abigail", {'name': 'Jennifer'}, {'name':'Adam'}]
```

What is the best way to sort the list such that strings are in the front, and objects come after?

```
["Abigail", "Kelsey", {'name':'Adam'}, {'name': 'Jennifer'}, {'name': 'Jorden'}]
```

Comment: Check the type of the values in your sort handler.

Comment: [so] is *not* a free code writing service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**.

Comment: You can use [the `typeof` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) to determine the type of an element in an array. Note that this will return `object` if an element is `null`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var myitems = [{'name': 'Jorden'},"Kelsey", "Abigail", {'name': 'Jennifer'}, {'name':'Adam'}];

myitems.sort(function(a, b) {
  if(typeof a === "string") {                                       // if a is a string
     if(typeof b === "string") return a.localeCompare(b);           // and b is a string, then compare the 2 strings a and b
     return -1;                                                     // otherwise (a is a string and b is an object) then make a go above b
  }
  else {                                                            // if a is an object
     if(typeof b === "object") return a.name.localeCompare(b.name); // and b is an object, then compare the 2 objects' names a.name and b.name
     return 1;                                                      // otherwise (a is an object and b is a string) then make a go bellow b
  }
});

console.log(myitems);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Assign to a variable
myitems = [{'name': 'Jorden'},"Kelsey", "Abigail", {'name': 'Jennifer'}, {'name':'Adam'}]
// Sort them
myitems = myitems.sort((x, y) => typeof(x) === 'string' ? -1 : 1)
```

Read more about the [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method and see how it works.

Basically, the sorting function takes two arguments `x` and `y` to sort. If the `x` is of type string, `-1` is returned so that `x` has higher priority than `y`, otherwise `+1` is returned to put `y` before `x`

Comment: Btw, you can remove the brackets of typeof as well

Comment: @dejakob I did not know that this is possible. Thanks!

Comment: I like the brevity. The one liner looks very beautiful.

Comment: @Rolando Note that this is ES2015 and above, so make sure you use a transpiler like Babel to transpile this for older browsers. I've used modern features given your question is tagged that.

Comment: This does not compare strings with each other and objects with each other. Please take a look at the expected output.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Indeed, it only moves strings first objects last, as the original poster requested.

Comment: Output does not match exactly, but I really like the elegance of this solution. Upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var myitems = [{'name': 'Jorden'},"Kelsey", "Abigail", {'name': 'Jennifer'}, {'name':'Adam'}]

var result = myitems.sort(function(a,b) {
  if(typeof a === 'string' && typeof b === 'object')
    return -1;
  else if(typeof a === 'object' && typeof b === 'string')
    return 1;
  else if(typeof a === 'string' && typeof b === 'string')
    return a.localeCompare(b);
  else
    return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
    
});
console.log(result);
```